# Image overlapping parent div responsiveness

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

What I'm trying to achieve is the image outside of the parent div's boundaries, which works in 1280x1024. How can I make this effect responsive?

Html:

```
                <div class='row'>
                <div class="divider">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="1s" data-wow-duration="1.5s">
                        <img src="http://karsbarendrecht.nl/5/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/responsive.png" alt="laptop tablet phone responsive"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="1s" data-wow-duration="1.5s">
                        <h1>bla bla bla.</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .divider{
    margin-top:100px;
    min-height:175px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    background-size: cover!important;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-image: url('http://karsbarendrecht.nl/5/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/triangles.svg'); 
}

    .divider div{
    top:-50px;
```

The following image show's my problem, with the top half being the desired effect. And the bottom half is what happens when resizing the screen to smaller resolutions.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By placing both the background image and the front image in HTML, and adding the following css rules they both scale the same.

```
       .divider div{
            top:-50px; // placing the image slightly above the divider div
            height:125%; // making the div containing the image bigger than the divider div
       }

       .divider img{
            width:100%; // just for this image because it isnt wide enough
            position:absolute; // make sure the image listens to top:-50px;
       }
```

ps: the images scale because of twitter bootstrap's css:

```
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the image is resizing itself but the parent div is not, in this case I would change the values in pixels to values in vh and vw (these are percentages of "viewport height" and "veiwport width": the height and width of the window you are resizing.) for example:

```
margin-top:100px;
```

would become

```
margin-top:8vh;
```

Comment: You are right about the problem, but the viewport height does not change on window resize. Percentages do but when height is given 100% it doesnt take 100% of the parent but it takes 100% of the screen.

P.S: the margin is just for the position, the 175px height is what i want to see changed to percentage, so it scales, but i cant seem to make it work.